# Pythonic way of moving temp files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

From what I gather, `open()` in really `io.open()`, a high level "wrapper" for `os.open()`. 
For other file operations like renaming and removing files I have to use `os` funcations like `os.remove` and `os.rename` a file or even `shutil.move` in some cases, like below:

```
import shutil
with open("/tmp/workfile", "w") as f:
  f.write("some stuff")

shutil.move(f.name, "finalfile")
```

Why is there no similar wrapper like open for removal/renaming?

Is there a better, perhaps more pythonic way of accomplishing above task?

It seems strange to have to do imports instead of maybe having rename and remove be methods in `f`, point it over to another file. Especially when `open()` requires no import.

*edit: I removed the `del f` at the end that seemed to anger a lot of people. I know it's not needed. I had it there to highlight that an `f`-object that no longer points to a removed file has very little use.*

Comment: Are you asking about removing files, or renaming (moving) files?

Comment: No need for `del f` at the end.

Comment: How frequently do you think people open files compared to moving/renaming/deleting files? What do you think is the overhead of importing a built-in module?

Comment: Opening a file results in state about that file being kept in memory: its name, its file descriptor, a pointer into its contents, etc. Everything else simply performs an operation, with no state being kept after the fact.

Comment: I feel like @DeepSpace and Daren Thomas's first two paragaphs hold the real answer here. Maybe I should have reformulated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@micke, wanna bet this is due to history? I'm guessing the `open` function was one of the first added to Python because, well... the creator of the language needed that early on.

I'd argue that having `open` as a built-in function is weird, not the other way around.

Also note that you're using the variable `f` outside of the `with` block. And the `with` block automatically calls `close` on `f` when the block exits, so the `del f` statement is not necessary. That's the whole point of using `with` blocks (forgetting to `.close()` is a very common mistake)

Comment: `del` being unnecessary has little to do with the `with` statement. `f` is still in scope, so the return value of `open` is not yet garbage-collected, despite the underlying file being closed.

Comment: @chepner are you saying that if I use `f`outside the `with` block, the file is kept in memory? I added `del` just because `f` becomes useless with its file unlinked.

Comment: @chepner, yes, technically true. I guess I just never thought of another reason to use `del` than to trigger the `close` - in fact, I hardly ever use `del`.

Comment: @micke, no, the file is not kept in memory. It is closed implicitly when the while block ends. `f` will still be a file-like object, but a closed one.